# Is it possible to have a manual gearbox?

Tags: need-for-speed-shift-2-unleashed

It would be the first car game I ever see that we can't switch between auto and manual transmission.

It doesn't appear in the settings and options, is there a way to shift between the two?

Comment: Don't know as I don't have this one but it's auto-only in the last NFS Hot Pursuit... Very far from the very first NFS... :-(

Comment: What platform are you on? Looking through various forums, I found this: "Assuming its the same as the 360 it should be under the controller settings. I think its on the second tab where you actually see the controller and I think its the second option from the top."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to Options -> Controls  and set Gears to Manual. You also have the option to select whether to use a clutch or not at that menu as well.

Answer (score 1):

What platform are you on? Looking through various forums, I found this: "Assuming its the same as the 360 it should be under the controller settings. I think its on the second tab where you actually see the controller and I think its the second option from the top."

[Source](http://forum.ea.com/eaforum/posts/list/5545303.page)

Comment: Please avoid asking questions in answers. Comments were invented to ask such questions.