# Can't set manual gears

Tags: need-for-speed-shift-2-unleashed

I just got SHIFT2 Unleashed and I like it, but I hate the automatic gearbox. I have made the changes but nothing happens. Manual gearshift and auto clutch.
Is there some trick to get the changes to stick?

Comment: Just making sure, you did the steps listed [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20209/is-it-possible-to-have-a-manual-gearbox)?